# Solve using Laplace and IVP $\displaystyle ay'' + by' +cy = t$ such that $\displaystyle y'(0)=0,y(0)=1$

Tags: laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

> Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ with $a \neq 0$. Solve the IVP
>
> $\displaystyle ay'' + by' + cy = t$
>
> Using Laplace Transform where $\displaystyle y'(0)=0,y(0)=1$

**My Attempt**

$\displaystyle a\mathcal L(y'') + b \mathcal L(y')+ c\mathcal L(y) = \mathcal L t$

$\displaystyle a[s^2y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)] + b[sy(s)-y(0)]+cy(s) = \frac{1}{s^2}$

$\displaystyle y(s)(as^2 + bs +c) -asy(0)-by(0) - ay'(0) =  \frac{1}{s^2}$

Plugging initial values $y'(0)=0$ and $y(0)=1$ we have:

$\displaystyle y(s) = \dfrac{as+b}{s^2(as^2+bs+c)}$

Now for the next part where I'm stuck with obtaining partial fractions and using Inverse Laplace since the constants are $a,b,c$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $as^2 + bs + c = a(s+r_+)(s+r_-)$ where $r_\pm^2 + b r_\pm/a +c/a=0$. Proceed from there. You don't need to find the roots until after you have the solution in terms of $r_\pm$. In other words, you know the quadratic in the denominator factors. Worry about how later.